# How to get UUIDs while monitoring beacons?

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android

I am using altbeacon reference app to work with beacons. I am getting null when I try print arg0 I get null while monitoring beacons.

```
@Override
 public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
    // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user 
 whenever a Beacon
    // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.
    System.out.println(arg0);
    System.out.println(arg0.getUniqueId());
    System.out.println(arg0.getId1());
    Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
}
```

How do i get the UUID here? Is it necessary to call ranging here because I am trying to make a foreground service and if I call ranging service everytime I get an didEnter event, wont it be heavy and get killed by the android system.
I previously attempted to do that and store results in a collection and see if a new beacon comes in the region then add it there, but resulted in the service being killed.

**Edit:** I tried the following

```
 @Override
  public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
    if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity");
        Intent RangingIntent = new Intent(this, Monitoring.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         getApplicationContext().startForegroundService(RangingIntent);
        } else  {
            getApplicationContext().startService(RangingIntent);
        }
        haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;
        } else {
        if (monitoringActivity != null) {
            Intent RangingIntent = new Intent(this, Monitoring.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {               
         getApplicationContext().startForegroundService(RangingIntent);
            } else  {
                getApplicationContext().startService(RangingIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

The ranging code

```
    public class Monitoring extends Service implements BeaconConsumer {

        protected static final String TAG = "RangingService";
        private BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            System.out.println("********STARTING RANGING*********");
            beaconManager.bind(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            beaconManager.unbind(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
            beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier()  {
                @Override
                public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                    if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion called with beacon count:  "+beacons.size());
                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(beacons.iterator().next()));
                        Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                    }
                }

            });

            try {
                beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
            } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
        }
    }
```

PS: Iam trying to get ranging logs when app is killed

Answer (score 0):

If you use a wildcard region where you set each identifier to null, then you simply cannot read the identifiers with the monitoring APIs.  Two options:

1. Define multiple regions, specifying the UUID for each, and then monitor all of those regions.  When you get a callback, the Region object passed as a parameter will contain the UUID when calling `region.getId1()`.
2. Use the ranging API in addition to the monitoring API. (You don't have to turn on ranging after didEnterRegion is called, you can just turn it on at the same time as monitoring and leave it on.)   When ranging is turned on, you'll get a callback to `didRangeBeaconsInRegion(...)` that contains a list of the actual beacons detected.  You can then read the first identifier from this callback.

Comment: I just tried doing that. received an error -  # HandleSigQuit # DumpForSigQuit # before # pid=12098. I used intent to startForegroundService for ranging without any UI.

Comment: An issue with adding in a separate foreground service is probably the cause of this issue, not ranging itself.   You really don't need to make it so complex, just start ranging at the same time as you start monitoring.

Comment: Oh that sounds right I suppose, but my use case need to get uuid of the beacon at the exact time of didEnterRegion. Would I need to keep track of new beacons entering and exit events for old beacons exiting in order to get uuids for correct events?

Comment: Understand that when using a wildcard region (all null identifiers) any beacon will match.  So if you have not yet gotten a didEnter callback it means no beacons are visible.  The next ranging callback after didEnterRegion is called will list the beacons that appeared that caused didEnterRegion to fire.  You can just set a class-level flag in didEnterRegion to tell you to process the UUIDs when the didRangeBeaconsInRegion call acknowledge comes.